# SQL Query to Get Upstream User On Downstream Serial Number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query, recursive-datastructures

I work in a specialty manufacturing facility, we do operations to make widgets.

One step in our manufacturing is highly specialized, only people with the `position_key` of `27433` can do it.

We have `Scrap` pieces with a `serial_no` and I'm trying to track them back to which person with the `position_key` of `27433` worked on the scrapped `serial_no` - this is challenging because our `serial_no` changes at every step in the process.

The database records below are for two scrapped `serial_no` pieces ( `S439773` and `S598045`) and all the previous operations before they were scrapped and who worked on them (`Add_by` = `Last_Name` )

```
Serial_No   Container_Status    From_Serial_No  Add_By  Last_Name   Position_Key  
S439773     Scrap               S438590         67005   Jones       22237
S598045     Scrap               S596759         67005   Jones       22237
S596759     Suspect             S589956         56011   Bryant      23028
S589956     OK                  S586597         1908350 Pippen      27433
S586597     OK                  S586083         56011   Bryant      23028
S436403     OK                  S435310         56011   Bryant      23028
S586083     OK                  S585319         67005   Jones       22237
S585319     OK                                  67271   Magic       23082
S438590     Suspect             S438537         67833   Sey         25742
S438537     OK                  S436095         67833   Sey         25742
S436095     OK                  S436403         1908349 Jordan      27433
S435310     OK                  S435283         1908349 Jordan      27433
S415897     OK                  10-00           67271   Magic       23082
S435283     OK                  S432977         1908349 Jordan      27433
S432977     OK                  S415897         1918880 Campbell    23028
```

To help here is the code to create the table:

```
declare @Something table
(
    Serial_no varchar(10)
    , Container_Status varchar(10)
    , From_Serial_No varchar(10)
    , Add_By varchar(50)
    , Last_Name varchar(10)
    , Position_Key varchar(10)
    )

    insert @Something values
    (   'S439773','Scrap','S438590','67005','Jones','22237'),
(   'S598045','Scrap','S596759','67005','Jones','22237'),
(   'S596759','Suspect','S589956','56011','Bryant','23028'),
(   'S589956','OK','S586597','1908350','Pippen','27433'),
(   'S586597','OK','S586083','56011','Bryant','23028'),
(   'S436403','OK','S435310','56011','Bryant','23028'),
(   'S586083','OK','s585319','67005','Jones','22237'),
(   'S585319','OK','','67271','Magic','23082'),
(   'S438590','Suspect','S438537',67833,'Sey','25742'),
(   'S438537','OK','S436095',67833,'Sey','25742'),
(   'S436095','OK','S436403',1908349,'Jordan','27433'),
(   'S435310','OK','S435283',1908349,'Jordan','27433'),
(   'S415897','OK','10-00','67271','Magic','23082'),
(   'S435283','OK','S432977','1908349','Jordan','27433'),
(   'S432977','OK','S415897','1918880','Campbell','23028')
```

The end result I'm trying to create is to return the `Scrap` piece `serial_no` with the person with the `position_key` of `27433` who worked on it earlier in the process.

In this example it would look like this:

```
Serial_No   Status   Position_27433_Person
S439773      Scrap   Jordan
S598045      Scrap   Pippen
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Me

Comment: What do you want returned if two "Masters" work on the same piece that gets scrapped?

Comment: Regardless of the answer to my above question you are going to need a recursive cte.

Comment: @SeanLange, brilliant question!  Ideally the very first one who worked on it.   It's likely that's where the problem occured, and that the second 'Master' was trying to fix the original mistake

Answer (score 1):

The recursive cte you were starting on was generally the right direction but had some logical flaws in there. I started by creating some usable data so that I could work on the issue. You should do this on future posts to make it easier for others.

This produces the output you said you wanted and should work as I understand the requirements.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Serial_no int
    , Container_Status varchar(10)
    , From_Serial_No int
    , Add_By varchar(50)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'OK', 0, 'NonMaster')
, (2, 'OK', 1, 'Master_1')
, (3, 'Scrap', 2, 'NonMaster')
, (4, 'OK', 0, 'NonMaster')
, (5, 'OK', 4, 'Master_2')
, (6, 'OK', 5, 'NonMaster')
, (7, 'Scrap', 6, 'NonMaster')

;

--The above is what you should post in future questions so the volunteers can work on your answer instead of setting up the question

with MyWidgets as
(
    select s.*, BaseNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Serial_No)
    from @Something s
    where s.From_Serial_No = 0

    union all

    select s.*, w.BaseNum
    from @Something s
    join MyWidgets w on w.Serial_no = s.From_Serial_No
)

select w.Serial_no
    , Status = w.Container_Status
    , x.Add_By
from MyWidgets w
cross apply
(
    select top 1 w2.Add_By
    from MyWidgets w2
    where w2.BaseNum = w.BaseNum
        and w2.Serial_no <= w.Serial_no
        and w2.Add_By like 'Master%'
    order by w2.Serial_no
) x
where w.Container_Status = 'Scrap'
order by w.BaseNum
    , w.Serial_no
```

Comment: @Sean_Lange, Thank u for feedback on asking questions better, will do moving forward.  I keep hitting the max recursion allowed.  Upping the recursion limit might be a temp fix but `where s.From_Serial_No = 0` is not a good filter.  I used '0' in my example data just to give a general 'started from somewhere' serial number to reference, I realize now they both point to '0' and why you used it - this was my error and I apologize.  I tried adjusting with `where s.container_status = 'Scrap'` which would be more appropriate to grab only serials that are scrap but can't get it to run, any tips?

Comment: You have to use a where predicate that will isolate the first entry in a given widget. If you use "Scrap" it will return only those which isn't going to work in your case as you need the other rows. Do you not have something in the data to indicate a first step? And hopefully in your real data you have something to indicate that each row belongs to a given instance of a widget.

Comment: In the real data I'm grabbing scrap pieces created in a time frame.  I dropped the time aspect of this to make the example as simple as possible.  This allows me to grab the serial numbers of the scrap pieces created.  I then have to use the recursive query to go through the serial numbers - outside of this method I do not have a way to get to the original serial number.  I don't have a way outside of this to know that each record belongs to a given instance of a widget.

Comment: Ouch!!! You are going to have to find a way to get to the first entry for a widget. Do you have a status (or two or three) that can be used to identify the end of a given widget? Is there any way to ensure that all of widget 1 rows are before any row for widget 2? If not you may be stuck due to a less than ideal data design.

Comment: @Sean_Lange, ouch is right!  There is a timestamp and serial numbers are always created in sequential order, between the two of those fields there is a way to make sure things are kept in order.  Per your suggestion I've updated my question with both this field and table creation code.  I'm in over my head - I can follow your example and understand it but this riddle is driving me crazy.  Thank you for helping!

Comment: OK do you ALWAYS have a gap between widgets? If so, how long or short can that gap be?

Comment: Yes, always gaps between widgets and all over the map.   However, the # of operations between when a `Scrap` piece is found and tracked back to the `Master`  is 1 to 10.  Time gaps as short as an hour up to months.  Can you do a ROWNUMBER()  but in reverse using the last `serial_no` where the `Scrap` piece was found?

Comment: I think it is time you provide some better sample data that is representative of the real situation. This is just too vague at this point to offer any coding solution.

Comment: based on your feedback I've made significant changes to the question. Hopefully it's more clear and possible to offer a coding solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a `FUNCTION`?

```
CREATE FUNCTION tf_GetPreviousSerialNumbers
(
    @serialNumber VARCHAR(7)
)
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE
        (SerialNumber VARCHAR(7))

AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @serialNumber IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TABLE
        SELECT Serial_No
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Serial_No = @serialNumber AND Position_Key = '27433'

        SET @serialNumber = (SELECT From_Serial_No FROM YourTable WHERE Serial_No = @serialNumber)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT yt1.Serial_No, yt1.Container_Status, yt2.Last_Name
FROM YourTable yt1
LEFT JOIN YourTable yt2 ON yt2.Serial_No IN (SELECT SerialNumber FROM tf_GetPreviousSerialNumbers(yt1.Serial_No))
WHERE yt1.Container_Status = 'Scrap'
```

There are some similar things you can do depending on your exact requirements. For example the function could return a single serial number if you aren't concerned about the duplicate 27433s.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? You pass in a variable and then do a loop continuing to select the same value over and over. This has many logical issues going on, it looks like an endless loop. And table valued functions that are more than a single select statement are horrible for performance.

Comment: @SeanLange It doesn't select the same value over and over again, it's selects the parent value recursively until there are no more parents. It adds only those values that have the desired Position_Key to the table returned. It's definitely a solution, it's performance may not be acceptable for all data sets.

Comment: I see the recursion stuff now. It is going to be an issue if that subquery ever returns more than 1 row. A loop is definitely not a good approach as we should always try to avoid RBAR processing. A recursive cte would be much better.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller, this end use of this would be to process thousands of records at a time.  It's also possible for more than 1 person with this `position_key` to process pieces.  Scenario is we knew the piece was bad, 2nd person in that `position_key` tried to fix it ,but piece still got scrapped anyways.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller I cannot create a function.  Just tried your solution and the T-SQL based web interface in our ERP system doesn't allow it.  I'm disappointed, appreciate the potential solution you offered.